# SQL to get data with condition as combination of two columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from table where 
COALESCE(HOURS, MINUTES) is not null 
and (if hours = null, then minutes >0)
and (if minutes = null then hours > 0)
and (minutes != 0 AND hours != 0)
```

How can I give last 3 sqls as SQL condition for oracle?

Sample data:

```
Hours Minutes
----- -------
1     22
null  33
0     13
0     0
null  null
10    0
10    null
```

In this scenerio it should return

```
Hours Minutes
----- -------
1     22
null  33
0     13
10    0
10    null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, based on your suggestions, i am able to fetch proper data. I am using conditions like:

select * from table where condition1 
        and (COALESCE(HOURS, MINUTES) is not null) 
        and (HOURS > 0 OR  MINUTES > 0)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you want:

```
where coalesce(hours, 0) + coalesce(minutes, 0) > 0
```

This basically treats `NULL` as 0 and makes sure that the sum is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Updated my query. Thanks for the comment.

So basically you need rows where either `hours` or `minutes` is not `null` or `0`. I think you need this (If I understand your requirement correctly)

```
with table1(Hours,Minutes) as
(select 1,22 from dual union
select null,33 from dual union
select 0,13 from dual union
select 0,0 from dual union
select null,null from dual union
select 10,0 from dual union
select 10,null from dual 
)
select * from table1
    where
        (hours is not null
        or 
        minutes is not null
        )
    and 
        (hours>0 or minutes>0)
```

Comment: That doesn't take account of the hours and minutes columns both being 0

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where 
COALESCE(HOURS, MINUTES) is not null 
and (minutes <> 0 AND hours <> 0)
and minutes>(case when hours is null then 0 else (minutes-1) end)
and hours>(case when minutes is null then 0 else (hours-1) end)
```

maybe something like this? a little porblematic since they can be null